# I can't access my music.

Tags: music

I used to be able to play my music by tapping the music app. Now when I tap it all I see is some woman listening on headphones and apple icon. This is not as good as listening to the music I've purchased. 
How can I get back to the good ol days of listening to my music rather than looking at this bird?

Answer (score 1):

Click "GO TO MY MUSIC". If the button isn't available, maybe the app froze. Press the Home-Button twice (quickly) and slide the app to the top to force-quit it. Then reopen it.